# How to propagate configuration changes of endorser to SDK

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Is there a mechanism to propagate the end point information to the client SDK according to the configuration change of Endoser?

Please let me know if anyone knows the details.

Comment: can you give an example of configuration change at endorser?

Comment: I agree with Artem Barger. What do you mean with "configuration change of Endoser"? In the client SDK you define to wich Peer are you going to send the proposal transaction. You have to change it if the endpoint changes.